# How to create a pdf using Fpdf in cakephp 2.0?

Tags: php, pdf, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, fpdf

I have actually got very far but my output is gibberish and not a formatted pdf as I expected. Here is the relevant code:

**JobsController:**

```
public function viewpdf() {
    App::import('Vendor', 'Fpdf', array('file' => 'fpdf/fpdf.php'));
    $this->layout = 'pdf'; //this will use the pdf.ctp layout

    $this->set('fpdf', new FPDF('P','mm','A4'));
    $this->set('data', 'Hello, PDF world');

    $this->render('pdf');

}
```

**View/Layouts/pdf.ctp:**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
    echo $content_for_layout;
?>
```

**View/Jobs/pdf.ctp:**

```
<?php
    $fpdf->AddPage();
    $fpdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $fpdf->Cell(40,10,$data);
    $fpdf->Output();
?>
```

with FPDF installed in the root/Vendors directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the response type in your controller function:

```
public function viewpdf() {
App::import('Vendor', 'Fpdf', array('file' => 'fpdf/fpdf.php'));
$this->layout = 'pdf'; //this will use the pdf.ctp layout

$this->response->type('pdf');

$this->set('fpdf', new FPDF('P','mm','A4'));
$this->set('data', 'Hello, PDF world');
$this->render('pdf');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In cake2 you can use a cleaner approach - with or without the new response object:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/11/21/serving-views-as-files-in-cake2/

The headers will be set by cake itself from the controller.
It's not good coding (anymore) to set them in the layout (I used to do that, as well^^).

These days the [CakePdf plugin](https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf) has matured quite a bit into a very useful tool for PDF generation.
I recommend using that in Cake2.x.

See http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/04/08/generating-pdfs-with-cakephp

Comment: for details on the new response object see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakeresponse

Comment: no I couldn't get this to work. Plus I am using FPDF not DOMPDF but I tried both packages. It suggests trying to load the pdf view from within the same action on the controller, which I find confusing.